# Chrome extension: calling event with onUpdated.addListener causes infinite refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I called the event handler whenever onUpdated in service_worker.

**service_worker.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if(changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url) {
        const domain = getDomainFromUrl(tab.url);
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {'tabId': tabId, 'url' : tab.url, 'domain': domain});
    }
});
```

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(({tabId, url, domain}, sender, response) => {
    
          // I tried to avoid repeated calls
          // by storing and retrieving values as arrays or storage
          // within content_script or service_worker.
          // some works...

         window.location.href = url

    }
```

However, every time it refreshes, neither service_worker nor content_script can't compares with the existing value(it seems to be initialized by refresh), and the extension refreshes infinitely recursively.

I want to refresh only once for a specific domain (part of the url). I need something like an object to store the domain for as long as the browser is up and running. Is it there?

Comment: Use chrome.storage or LocalStorage.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It sounds like you need to to set the variable using ```chrome.storage.local.set({'var_name': variable})``` and then retrieve it in an async callback ```const variable = await chrome.storage.local.get(['var_name']).then(data => { return data['var_name'] })```

Comment: You've shown us your code, but you haven't told us what you're trying to accomplish, and why.